# Length of current selection in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Do you know any *easy* way to find out what is the length of the current selection in Eclipse?
i.e. I select a line fragment and would like to know how many characters are there?

Usually, I count them manually, but that's stupid. When being desperate, I move to the start, check the column number, move to the end, check the column number, subtract, think a minute if I should add 1 or not... and my selection is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, Notepad++ is a good solution.  Open a new tab, copy and paste in there and the length of the document listed at the bottom of the window is the number of characters you have.

Comment: I add this just because one has to be careful with websites and what might happen to your data if you really care about it.

Comment: This solution is better than the other one because in notepad++, one can get rid of the unwanted characters with find and replace, which is not possible with the other given website.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way? Copy the text and paste it to a counting script, like this site:

http://charcount.com/

(Warning: the site's background may hurt your eyes.)

Eclipse *does* support a Selection object, if you're into its API:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html#example